# How to set fallback value for x:Static

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Subj.

Can do like this to avoid having *blurish* view in design:

```
<Window.Effect>
    <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding Blur, FallbackValue=0}"/>
</Window.Effect>
```

But what about

```
<TextBlock ext="{x:Static local:App.Version}"/>
```

at design time auto-property `App.Version` is `null`. I can make it normal property and assign private field *default value*:

```
private static string _version = "Version1.0.0.0";
public static string Version { get { return _version; } }
```

Still there can be a situation when I want *non-default* value to be displayed. To example,

```
"Test long version string to be visible in designer only"
```

And yes, I understand, what `Binding` and `Static` are different in someway, yet, is there a way to achieve what I want? I  also though to pass `App.Version` into ViewModel and bind View to it via Binding, but that's even worse (effort-wise), though more mvvm-conceptish.

Comment: Instead of assigning some default value for the field `_version`, you can set it to `string.Empty`. so that the textblock text value is empty during design time.

Comment: @RameshDurai, what if `version` is `""`, but I want to display `"Test long version string to be visible in designer only"` in designer only, without touching *default* value?

Comment: You can check for design mode in the viewmodel constructor `if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) { _version = "Test long version string to be visible in designer only" }else {_version = "Default Value}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:App.Version}, TargetNullValue='In designer'}" />
```

Note that you have to use `TargetNullValue` as `FallbackValue` is used when `Binding` cannot get value, which should not be the case for `static` property.